# call rest server codeigniter using file_get_contents

Tags: codeigniter, api, rest, file-get-contents

here my rest server controller

```
<?php

require(APPPATH.'libraries/REST_Controller.php');

class Server extends REST_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
            date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Jakarta");
            $this->load->model('server_model');
    }


    function customer_get()
    {
        if($this->get('id')){
            $users = $this->server_model->get_customer_by_id($this->get('id'));
        }else{
            $users = $this->server_model->get_customer_all();
        }

        if($users){
            $this->response($users);
        }else{
            $this->response(array('error' => 'Data tidak ditemukan!'));
        }
    }   


    public function customer_post()
    {
        $data = array(
                    'ktm'=>$this->post('ktm'),
                    'ktm_image'=>$this->post('ktm_image'),
                    'expired_ktm'=>$this->post('expired_ktm'),
                    'sim'=>$this->post('sim'),
                    'hp'=>$this->post('hp'),
                    'email'=>$this->post('email'),
                    'password'=>md5($this->post('password')),
                    'fakultas'=>$this->post('fakultas'),
                    'jurusan'=>$this->post('jurusan'),
                    'alamat'=>$this->post('alamat'),
                    'tanggal_lahir'=>$this->post('tanggal_lahir')
                );

        $query = $this->server_model->create_customer($data);

             if($query){
                $this->response($query);
             }else{
                $this->response(array('error' => 'Tambah data gagal!'));
             }
    }


    public function customer_put()
    {
        $id = $this->put('id');
        $data = array(
                    'ktm'=>$this->put('ktm'),
                    'ktm_image'=>$this->put('ktm_image'),
                    'expired_ktm'=>$this->put('expired_ktm'),
                    'sim'=>$this->put('sim'),
                    'hp'=>$this->put('hp'),
                    'email'=>$this->put('email'),
                    //'password'=>$this->put('password'),
                    'fakultas'=>$this->put('fakultas'),
                    'jurusan'=>$this->put('jurusan'),
                    'alamat'=>$this->put('alamat'),
                    'tanggal_lahir'=>$this->put('tanggal_lahir')
                );

        $query=$this->server_model->update_customer($data,$id);

             if($query){
                $this->response($query);
             }else{
                $this->response(array('error' => 'Edit data gagal!'));
             }
    }


    public function customer_delete(){
        $id = $this->delete('id');

        $query = $this->server_model->delete_customer($id);

            if($query){
                $this->response($query);
            }else{
                $this->response(array('error' => 'Hapus data gagal!'), 404);
            }   
    }   

}
```

how to call every method in rest server like get, post, put, delete and send data from client but use file_get_contents. i use rest server library codeigniter.

i've try use rest client library in codeigniter, and it's totally works, but i need to use file_get_contents now, but i don't know how to call it's, especially for send data for post, put, and delete.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You must create context for the call, like this:

```
<?php
// Create a stream
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
              "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n"
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

// Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
$file = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/', false, $context);
?>
```

See [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.file-get-contents.php) function documentation on php.net